# Python scripting for ParaView: Colorbar placement

Tags: python, vtk, paraview

Is there any way to arbitrarily place a colorbar?

Take for instance the following Python code into ParaView's shell:

```
#### import the simple module from the paraview
from paraview.simple import *
#### disable automatic camera reset on 'Show'
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

# create a new 'Wavelet'
wavelet1 = Wavelet()

# get active view
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
# uncomment following to set a specific view size
# renderView1.ViewSize = [1229, 814]

# show data in view
wavelet1Display = Show(wavelet1, renderView1)
# trace defaults for the display properties.
wavelet1Display.Representation = 'Outline'
wavelet1Display.ColorArrayName = ['POINTS', '']
wavelet1Display.GlyphType = 'Arrow'
wavelet1Display.ScalarOpacityUnitDistance = 1.7320508075688779
wavelet1Display.Slice = 10

# reset view to fit data
renderView1.ResetCamera()

# set scalar coloring
ColorBy(wavelet1Display, ('POINTS', 'RTData'))

# rescale color and/or opacity maps used to include current data range
wavelet1Display.RescaleTransferFunctionToDataRange(True)

# change representation type
wavelet1Display.SetRepresentationType('Volume')

# get color transfer function/color map for 'RTData'
rTDataLUT = GetColorTransferFunction('RTData')

# get opacity transfer function/opacity map for 'RTData'
rTDataPWF = GetOpacityTransferFunction('RTData')

# show color bar/color legend
wavelet1Display.SetScalarBarVisibility(renderView1, True)

#### saving camera placements for all active views

# current camera placement for renderView1
renderView1.CameraPosition = [0.0, 0.0, 66.92130429902464]
renderView1.CameraParallelScale = 17.320508075688775
```

I can make the colorbar horizontal but I can't find a way to modify its placement. See figure below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get the scalarbar corresponding to the lookup table (rTDataLUT) and the render view (renderView1) :

```
scalarbar = GetScalarBar(rTDataLUT, renderView1)
```

Then set the position of the bottom left corner of the scalarbar with the Position property. This position is expressed as a ratio of the render view size in each direction. Default value should be [0.85, 0.05].
For instance :

```
scalarbar.Position = [0.85, 0.2]
```

Finally, update your render view with Render() :

```
Render(renderView1)
```

Comment: This does exactly what I need. Thanks!